# Why Pandas ExcelWriter is truncating a dataframe's cell content?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

One of the cells' value in a dataframe is a very long string. When pandas writes it to an excel sheet, that value is getting truncated. Any reason why? Below is my code snippet.

```
excel_path = './{}_somename.xlsx'.format(name)
options = {'strings_to_formulas': False, 'strings_to_urls': False}
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path, engine='openpyxl', options=options)
for df_name, df in df_dict.items():
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=str(df_name), startrow=0, index=False)
writer.save()
```

example of the very long string inside the cell: `"asdasdas&reg; aadsdas Psgdfgjj (4 hgjhj, 4r A77 @1.20 erer)|Ahjdks A7373X Hkjnksds (9 Djhks @ 1.50YUx)"`. Actual string could be 10,000,000 chars long.

Note: For confidentiality reasons, I cannot share the exact string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Openpxyl writes Excel 2007 (`.xlsx`) files](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/) and these files have a [32,767 character limit per cell](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

10,000,000 characters will therefore never work.